# asp:UpdatePanel / Custom Control / RegisterClientScriptResource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have built a custom control that has a small amount of JavaScript. The JS is maintained as an embeded resource. When my control is rendered, I added it to the page as follows:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(
    GetType(), "Resources.MyControl.js");
```

The control works just fine but when it is rendered inside of an update panel, I am guessing that the JS resource is being added to the page object which is not being sent back to the client (only the contents inside the of the update panel make it back to the client.)

I could add the JS to my application library which fixes the issue as it is loaded at the begining of the initial page request. Any other fixes? Any way to use RegisterClientScriptResource from within an update panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer more or less here:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1040033/1445844.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your script with the page ScriptManager to work within an update panel.

Luckily, you don't need to find the instance of the scriptmanager on the page, because there is a handy static class, simply add:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(this.GetType(), "Resources.MyControl.js");
```

To your control and you are set.